# PowerShell Hashtable values being removed from second hashtable outside of loop

Tags: powershell, hashtable, powershell-5.0

I'm sure that title isn't very clear, and for that I apologize. I've run into a bit of an issue with a script that I'm writing and am hoping for some assistance figuring out what is going on. I figured out how to resolve the issue, I'm more looking for *why* this is happening. The script is over 3k lines long, but the snippet I wrote below reproduces the same issue.

I have three hash tables, DeviceList, AllDevices and RemovedDevices. Devicelist is laid out explicitly, and AllDevices equals DeviceList. Within a loop, items that exist in RemovedDevices are removed from DeviceList. Even though AllDevices is only modified at the beginning in this sample, the devices are still being removed from it.

```
$DeviceList = @{"server1" = "email1"; "server2" = "email2"; "server3" = "email3"}
$AllDevices = $DeviceList
$RemovedDevices = @{"server1" = "email1"; "server2" = "email2"}

foreach($RemovedDevice in $RemovedDevices.GetEnumerator())
  {
  $DeviceList | where {$_.ContainsKey($RemovedDevice.Key)} | % {$_.Remove($RemovedDevice.Key)}
  }
$AllDevices
```

Running the above text, $AllDevices is modified to only contain the server3 info, where it should still contain all 3 servers.

If I modify the second line to:

```
$AllDevices += $DeviceList
```

Then AllDevices maintains all 3 values. Using breakpoints and stepping through on the first version, I have verified that AllDevices is not being hit after the first time.

My overall question is: Why is AllDevices being modified to equal DeviceList after the loop has finished? If it's only called once at the beginning, shouldn't it's value remain static despite modifications to DeviceList? Rebuilding an array using a similar method doesn't overwrite AllDevices so I imagine it's a hashtable quirk.

PSVersion                      5.0.10586.117

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is AllDevices being modified to equal DeviceList after the loop has finished?

Because `$AllDevices` is just a *reference* to the same underlying object as `$DeviceList`

> If it's only called once at the beginning, shouldn't it's value remain static despite modifications to DeviceList?

If `$AllDevices` was an *identical* object, sure, but it is not just identical - it *is* the same object.

Fortunately, hashtables implement the `ICloneable` interface, so for shallow hashtables, you can use the `Clone()` method:

```
$DeviceList = @{"server1" = "email1"; "server2" = "email2"; "server3" = "email3"}
$AllDevices = $DeviceList.Clone()

$RemovedDevices = @{"server1" = "email1"; "server2" = "email2"}

foreach($RemovedDevice in $RemovedDevices.GetEnumerator())
{
    if($DeviceList.ContainsKey($RemovedDevice.Key))
    {
        $DeviceList.Remove($RemovedDevice.Key)
    }
}
$AllDevices
```

*I found the usage of a hashtable with `Where-Object` super unreadable (not to mention unnecessarily slow), but functionally the above is the same as your original `foreach` loop body*

Comment: I never knew that by doing it that way it was just a reference and not a separate object. Thank you very much for your explanation!